# GMock cannot disambiguate overloaded function

Tags: c++, googletest, smart-pointers, googlemock

We have a mock class with an overloaded method. Variable/class names have been altered

```
class MockBuilderClass
: public IBuilder
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(Method, IBuilder& (const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IData>>& data));
    MOCK_METHOD1(Method, IBuilder& (const std::shared_ptr<IData>& data));
};
```

Interface for context

```
class IBuilder
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<IThing> Build() = 0;

    virtual IBuilder& Method(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IData>>& data) = 0;
    virtual IBuilder& Method(const std::shared_ptr<IData>& data) = 0;
};
```

In a test we do an expect call like this

```
auto expectedData = std::make_shared<DataItem>("Data");
EXPECT_CALL(*mockBuilder, Method(TypedEq<std::shared_ptr<IData>&>(expectedData)))
    .WillOnce(ReturnRef(*mockBuilder));
```

This is apparently not sufficent to disambiguate the call to method. we get an error:

> E0304 no instance of overloaded function "MockBuilder::gmock_Method" matches the argument list

I have tried various combinations of the other matcher functions (Matcher, Eq, ref, etc...) and have made no progress. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mockBuilder, Method(TypedEq<std::shared_ptr<IData>&>(expectedData)))
    .WillOnce(ReturnRef(*mockBuilder));
```

Needed to be:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mockBuilder, Method(TypedEq<const std::shared_ptr<IData>&>(expectedData)))
    .WillOnce(ReturnRef(*mockBuilder));
```